# Calculate the area using parametric plot

Tags: geometry

i would like to ask a question

if we have some parametric plot and it will be a shape, can we use "area" function to calculate that shape?

Here is the simple program

```
\[Alpha] = \[Pi];
\[Alpha]1 = .5 \[Pi];
g[1] = ParametricPlot[{-8 + u Cos[\[Alpha]1], 
    u Sin[\[Alpha]1]}, {u, -8, 8}, PlotStyle -> Green];
g[2] = ParametricPlot[{u Cos[\[Alpha]], 8 + u Sin[\[Alpha]]}, {u, -8, 
    8}, PlotStyle -> Green];
g[3] = ParametricPlot[{8 + u Cos[\[Alpha]1], 
    u Sin[\[Alpha]1]}, {u, -8, 8}, PlotStyle -> Green];
g[4] = ParametricPlot[{u Cos[\[Alpha]], -8 + u Sin[\[Alpha]]}, {u, -8,
     8}, PlotStyle -> Green];
ar = {};
AppendTo[gar, g[1]];
AppendTo[gar, g[2]];
AppendTo[gar, g[3]];
AppendTo[gar, g[4]];
Show[gar, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
Show[gar, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotRange -> All] //BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics // Area
```

> `256`

Comment: its not working, i receive the this error

BoundaryMeshRegion::buncl: At least one boundary was not closed in BoundaryMeshRegion[{{-8.,-8.},{-8.,-7.84297},{-8.,-7.68594},{-8.,-7.34547},{-8.,-7.02755},{-8.,-6.71588},{-8.,-6.37778},<<37>>,{-8.,6.02834},{-8.,6.36812},{-8.,6.68533},{-8.,6.99632},{-8.,7.16501},{-8.,7.33371},<<162>>},{{},{Line[{<<1>>}]}}]. >>

Comment: @葉柏樂AbdullahSyafiq  Or `DiscretizeGraphics /@ {g[1], g[2], g[3], g[4]} // RegionUnion // 
   Show // BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics // Area`

Comment: i dont know why, it still not work in that program

Comment: @葉柏樂AbdullahSyafiq   version 13.1

Comment: maybe because i still use version 10.0